# Is there a way to send text to an aspcontrol via jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is there a way to send data to an aspcontrol say a label called label1? Via jquery?

I know jquery only likes html but is there a way to just send the raw text to an asp control using a similar method below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var x = $('textarea').val();
                $('textarea').val('');
                var label = $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>");
                var newdiv = $("<div></div>").html(x).attr('id', 'test');
                $('#test1').append(newdiv);
                var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                label.text(serializer.serializeToString(newdiv));
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bigger issue is asp.net changes the id and trying to get that in the code isn't that easy.

Can you use the name attribute? If so you can just look for the name attribute containing your name using the jquery selector '[ name *="YourName"]'

EDIT: I meant to add firebug is a great help for examining page elements and figuring exactly what you can use (Ex: asp.net adds a name attribute to a button by default) and whats going on (like your return false failing) then tweaking your jquery from the watch window.

Sample asp.net form content:

```
<p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" name="TextBox1" runat="server" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></p>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" name="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</p>

<div id="test1"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('[name*= "Button1"]').click(function () {
        var x = $('[name*= "TextBox1"]').val();
        var newdiv = $("<div></div>").html(x).attr('id', 'test');

        $('#test1').append(newdiv);
        $('[name*= "Label1"]').text($('#test1').html());
        $('[name*= "TextBox1"]').val('');

        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: yeah thats cool but... my code inserts divs into a specific area of my page which holds user defined text  what I want to do is store the html tags alog with the content the user adds to a asp label using my method. But it doesnt work?

Comment: I updated my code, and it grabs the html, but it feels a bit hacky to me.  I basically just grabbed the contents of the div that you are appending rather then the content and html of the div you just created. What I encountered was when you use the html method it doesn't grab the outer html, I'll play around with it a bit more, but maybe this can at least point you in the right direction

Comment: It returns undefined, I didn't have time to look it up other then a quick google search showed there's outerHTML plugins but that's as far as I got.

Comment: my label still isnt setting anything even with your first post?

Comment: by that i mean the text of the label isnt changing it just says Label on button click

Comment: Did you set the name attributes of the text and label fields, and not the button? (at least in .net 4 it sets the name for asp buttons automatically) Also are there any javascript errors that may be breaking it?

Comment: ok thats it done! woop thanks man there is one other thing tho how do i turn the label invisible?

Comment: if i turn it invisible with the propertys tab it isnt rendered then i cant write to it with your function

Comment: Hey, running to a meeting but off the top of my head try using css style="display:none;".

Comment: Btw, the above should work, but standards-wise, you shouldn't inject styling into the element itself, the best practices is to put the 'display:none' into a class and set the class on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it without jQuery:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="App_Resources/JavaScript/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="testLabel" runat="server" Text="test" />

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function ()
                {
                    var label = document.getElementById("<%= testLabel.ClientID %>");
                    var div = document.createElement("div");

                    div.innerText = "content";

                    label.innerText = div.outerHTML;
                });
            </script>
        </form>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this selector $("[id$='Label1']").html(newdiv.outerHTML)

Comment: your edit still doesnt work ive reedited my post to see if I have it correct Label1 is the asp control

Comment: im gettin postback aswell for some reasong even altho return is set to false

Comment: I'm not sure why you have $(document).ready inside of your click handler...I would reverse that. You should hook up the click handler inside $(document).ready.